# select default tab of the tabbarcontroller before opening it when using storyboard and segue

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

In my iOS application I have `tabbarviewcontroller` that it is not the firt view controller of the app.

Actually it is the second view controller. The first view controller is a dashboard and then by pressing one of the buttons application push the `tabbarcontroller` to the navigation bar and show the `tabbarcontroller`(I do all with storyboard)

Based on some situation the default tab that tabbarviewcontroller should show is diffrence. For example, some time I should open the tabbarcontroller so that shows second tab. Some times I should open it so that show first tab. Does somebody know How we can do it? I search the web but do not find any good answer.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Deciding which tab should be selected or actually selecting the tab?

Comment: I don't know how to select the tab before opening the tabbarcontroller

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITabBar` and `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can set the selectedIndex of the controller. Try `[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:myInt];`

If you are using a segue, you should set that in your prepare for segue method. Here's an example.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myIdentifier"]){  
        [((UITabBarController*)segue.destinationViewController) setSelectedIndex:myInt];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using storyboard and do not defined the tabbar in the codes. I show tabbarcontroller by creating segue in the storyboard

Comment: I added a little code sample for using prepareForSegue. you'll want to add this in the view controller that is segueing to the tabbarcontroller